# How to create pipe delimited csv file in multipart form data in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Facing difficulty to create pipe delimited csv file in multipart form data in dataweave

I am trying to send a csv file with pipe("|") separated value to an api as multipart form data. But after creation of multipart form data the content is transforming into comma (",") separated.
Could anyone help me to send pipe separated content to api.

I'm using below script please suggest any modification

```
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
---
{
    "parts": {
        "upload": {
            "headers": {
                "Content-Disposition": {
                    "name": "upload",
                    "filename": "test.csv",
                },
                "Content-Type": "application/csv"
            },
            "content": payload
        }
    }
}
```

Payload:

```
id|name
001|test
002|test
003|test
```

current output:

```
------=_Part_9925_416179401.1704798991668
Content-Type: application/csv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="test.csv"

id,name
001,test
002,test
003,test

------=_Part_9925_416179401.1704798991668--
```

Desired output:

```
------=_Part_9925_416179401.1704798991668
Content-Type: application/csv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="test.csv"

id|name
001|test
002|test
003|test

------=_Part_9925_416179401.1704798991668--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have is not how to create a CSV but how to do so inside a multipart output.

Try using the write() function to create CSV data while setting the separator property:

```
"content": write(payload, "application/csv", {separator:"|"})
```

Answer (score 0):

So your current code, when I run it in the DWL playground outputs your desired output but I think if your goal is to create a csv file content something like this would do the job:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload
```

You could store that as a var csvContent and then anything that requires the input such as an sftp file transfer, just add the vars.csvContent.

If you need the other details your current code works but you can further alter the csv content before adding the multipart content to it. Such as:

```
output application/csv header=false, escape="|"
---
payload
```

There is more info on the options for [csv format handling in the Mule docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dataweave-formats-csv)

I hope this helps.